# Is using a visor allowed in pop warner football?

Tags: rules, american-football, equipment

I play pop warner football, and I want to get an iridium visor, am I allowed to wear it?

I know that in some leagues tinted visors are not allowed but are what about in pop warner?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are allowed as long as they are clear.  One of the things that officials go through are safety classes.  Part of that is dealing with head/back/neck injuries.  If something happened a referee or medic would not take your helmet off.

Therefore they would need to see your eyes clearly and be able to run basic tests.  Clear is perfectly fine.  If you were looking for clear with a slight color tint I would specifically ask the league president of your league - email him - but as a young athlete I would make sure it was purely clear so I didn't have an AWAY referee make me take it off.